# How do I pass an unknown value to a choice key in pgfkeys?

Tags: pgfkeys

Why is the parameter value not being passed to my code for the unknown key value here?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfkeys}

\makeatletter
\def\ae@size{2cm}
\pgfkeys{/ae/example/.cd,
  size/.is choice,
  size/small/.code=\def\ae@size{I am small},
  size/medium/.code=\def\ae@size{I am medium},
  size/large/.code=\def\ae@size{I am large},
  size/.unknown/.code={\typeout{UNKNOWN  ----> #1}\def\ae@size{I am customized to#1}},
}
\newcommand\problem[1]{%%
  \pgfkeys{/ae/example/.cd,#1}%%
  \ae@size  
  \par
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\problem{size=small}
\problem{size=medium}
\problem{size=large}
\problem{size=a different size}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel Seems to work without expansion.  Why the recommendation to also expand?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `.is choice` handler basically does two things.

In your case, it setups the `size` key as if you would do:

```
size/.style={/ae/example/size/#1}
```

However, before that style (`size/#1`) is executed, the argument `#1` is saved in `\pgfkeys@was@choice`.

This macro `\pgfkeys@was@choice` is then used in the definition of the `size/.unknown` code to give a proper error message.

You can overwrite that `.unknown` handler to do things, of course. In this case, you can use `\pgfkeys@was@choice`. You can also use `\pgfkeyscurrentname`.

The difference can be seen, if one misuses a `.is choice` key by using something like:

```
size={unknown=arg}
```

The macro `\pgfkeyscurrentname` would give `unknown` (just the key name), `\pgfkeys@was@choice` would expand to `unknown=arg`. The `#1` you used in your definition of the `.unknown` code would be `arg` then.

As key names can only consist of expandable content, you can safely `\edef` `\pgfkeys@was@choice` or `\pgfkeyscurrentname`. This also means, you cannot do `size=a \emph{different} size`. (The possible, unusual `#1` may contain anything, of course, but I am using `\edef` on that in this example anyway.)

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfkeys}
\makeatletter
\def\ae@size{2cm}
\pgfkeys{/ae/example/.cd,
  size/.is choice,
  size/small/.code=\def\ae@size{I am small},
  size/medium/.code=\def\ae@size{I am medium},
  size/large/.code=\def\ae@size{I am large},
  size/.unknown/.code=%
    \edef\ae@size{I am customized to ``\pgfkeys@was@choice''. Argument: ``#1''}}
\newcommand\problem[1]{%%
  \pgfkeys{/ae/example/.cd,#1,because/.code=}%%
  \ae@size\par}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\problem{size=small}
\problem{size=medium}
\problem{size=large}
\problem{size=a different size}
\problem{size={Where is my=argument?}}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]