# Selectively ignoring some pgfkeys based on the existence of a tikz style

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfkeys

I want to be able to modify the style of some parts of a complex picture depending on a `tag` on nodes or pathes (precisely, I have a complex architecture schematic and I want to selectively highlight some datapathes). And I to facilitate maintenance of the picture, I prefer a single source.

One way to do that is:

1. to declare the `tags` as empty `pgfkeys` styles
2. and to modify their value on demand.

---

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
    \pgfkeys{/tikz/.cd,<slide 1>/.style={}}
    \pgfkeys{/tikz/.cd,<slide 2>/.style={}}
    \pgfkeys{/tikz/.cd,<slide 3>/.style={}}
    \pgfkeys{/tikz/.cd,<slide 4>/.style={}}

    \newcommand{\complexpicture}{

  \node[draw, <slide 1>] at (0,0) {box 1};  
  \node[draw, <slide 2>] at (2,0) {box 2};
  \node[draw, <slide 3>] at (4,0) {box 3};
  \node[draw, <slide 4>] at (6,0) {box 4};
}

General overview (all tags are ignored)
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \complexpicture
\end{tikzpicture}

Highlight first item    
\begin{tikzpicture}[<slide 1>/.style={very thick}]
  \complexpicture
\end{tikzpicture}

Highlight second item
\begin{tikzpicture}[<slide 2>/.style={very thick}]
  \complexpicture
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Of course, it works, but the need to previously declare `tags` is unflexible and inelegant.

So I tried to filter out `< tags >` with `pgfkeys`, except when a style exists. I used `first char syntax` to detect an initial `<`.

I did not succeed to declare styles starting with a `<`. So tikzpicture styles are in `/tag/name/.style` and I filter out `< name >` pgfkey, unless `/tag/name` exist.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\newcommand{\complexpicture}{
  \node[draw, <slide 1>] at (0,0) {box 1};  
  \node[draw, <slide 2>] at (2,0) {box 2};
  \node[draw, <slide 3>] at (4,0) {box 3};
  \node[draw, <slide 4>] at (6,0) {box 4};
}

\pgfkeys{
  /handlers/first char syntax=true,
  /handlers/first char syntax/the character </.initial=\mykeymacro
}
\def\mykeymacro#1{\mykeyparser#1\someendtext}
\def\mykeyparser<#1>\someendtext{
  \pgfkeysifdefined{/tag/#1}{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tag/#1}}{}
}

General overview (all tags are ignored)\\
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \complexpicture
\end{tikzpicture}

Highlight first item\\
\begin{tikzpicture}[/tag/slide 1/.style={very thick}]
  \complexpicture
\end{tikzpicture}

Highlight second item\\
\begin{tikzpicture}[/tag/slide 2/.style={very thick}]
  \complexpicture
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Actually, it does not work. `< tags >` are properly filtered out and there is no pgfkeys error, but **all** theses keys are suppressed and the styles declared in the `\tikzpicture` are never activated. I tried some variations on this scheme, but none did work.

Probably I am missing something...

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Could you please elaborate a tiny bit more on what you are trying to achieve, and, in particular, why? The current output can easily be achieved by putting the nodes in a `matrix` and saying `column 2/.style={thick}`, say. (Most likely I just do not understand the purpose of that exercise.)

Comment: Does [How do I pass an unknown value to a choice key in pgfkeys?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/149982/4301) or [How to define a style of undefined key choice? (duplicate)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/426493/4301) answer help?

Comment: This is a MWE. Actually, the picture is ~200 lines and describes the architecture of a processor, with registers, operators and busses. What I want to do is to have several versions. The regular one and others where the path used to implement some instructions is highlighted in red. The picture is fairly complex and can be largely improved,so I want a unique version and a way to easily modify styles of some parts of the picture **with a unique code**..

Comment: @Peter Grill Thanks for the links. Actually, the problem is not a problem of key choice. I want to tag some parts of a picture and say "apply this style where tag=sometag". But a node can have either no tag or one or several tags, and even a picture can define styles for several tags (for instance to highlight step1, step2..step9 and to highlight all the steps at once).

Comment: I had a similar issue and the solution I used is to have my picture in a separate file (using the `standalone` class). Each picture sets all the necessary styles required by the figure: `\tikzset{Draw Style 1/.provide style={}}`, ..., `\tikzset{Node Style 1/.provide style={}}`, etc (or those can be set to some default value if needed). That way, when I invoke this figure, I can override a select subset of the styles as desired. The handler `.provide style` is defined in [Is there something like \providetikzstyle similar to \providecommand?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/22640/4301).

Answer (score 1):

I finally found a solution thanks to the unkonw handler and this trick can be useful to others.

Just define an unknown handler for a complete family that provides an empty style. And it is sufficient to redefine the style in the tikzpicture.

Here is a working example with several tags and several styles.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\newcommand{\complexpicture}{
  \node[draw, blue, /tag/slide 1] at (0,0) {box 1};  
  \node[draw, rounded corners, /tag/slide 2, /tag/slide 3] at (2,0) {box 2}; % double tag
  \node[draw, green, /tag/slide 3] at (4,0) {box 3};
  \node[draw, /tag/slide 4] at (6,0) {box 4};
}

\pgfkeys{/tikz/highlight/.style={red, very thick}}
\pgfkeys{/tikz/grey out/.style={opacity=0.4}}

\pgfkeys{/tag/.is family, /tag, 
.unknown/.code = {
    \pgfkeyssetvalue{\pgfkeyscurrentpath/\pgfkeyscurrentname}{}
}

General overview (all tags are ignored)\\
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \complexpicture
\end{tikzpicture}

Highlight first item\\
\begin{tikzpicture}[/tag/slide 1/.style=highlight]
  \complexpicture
\end{tikzpicture}

Highlight second item and grey out slide 3 and 4\\
\begin{tikzpicture}[/tag/slide 2/.style=highlight, /tag/slide 3/.style=grey out,
                    /tag/slide 4/.style=grey out]]
  \complexpicture
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Maybe it is also possible to define hierarchical tags in order to be able to change the style of either individual tags /tag/foo/bar or of a tag hierarchy /tag/foo/* at once.

Thanks to all.